# Passing entire Model from a View back to the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, controller, postback

I got a list of:

```
public class Items
{
    public String Nro_Item { get; set; }
    public Sucursal Sucursal { get; set; }
    public Areas Area { get; set; }
    public Sectores Sector { get; set; }
    public bool ID_Estado { get; set; }
}
```

I'm passing it to this view:

```
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc
@model IEnumerable<TrackingOperaciones.Controllers.Items>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ver Items";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<br/>
@using (Html.BeginForm("CargarRecibidos", "Recepcion", FormMethod.Post))
{    
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Numero
        </th>
        <th>
            Sucursal
        </th>
        <th>
            Area
        </th>
        <th>
            Sector
        </th>
    </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nro_Item)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sucursal.descripcion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area.descripcion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sector.Descripcion)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.ID_Estado)
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
<p>
    <input class="btn" name="Guardar" type="submit" value="Guardar"/> |
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver al listado de Recepción", "Index")
</p>
}
```

Until there everything is fine: Now the problem is getting back the entire model with the checked values in a controller for processing it like this one:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CargarRecibidos(IEnumerable<Items> items)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //do something here
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

But i'm falling miserably because "items" came back empty in the postback

i'm guess something is wrong with the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CargarRecibidos", "Recepcion"))
{  
    <input class="btn" name="Guardar" type="submit" value="Guardar"/>
}
```

please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IEnumerable

Then the controller input parameter will be List

Perhaps also consider using AJAX POST with JSON objects in place of a form submit (more modern/elegant) but submits are fine too.

Comment: Ok, now everything is IEnumerable, but still the same problem.

Comment: Are you seeing in the browser developer tools what is actually being POSTED? Also try adding the parameter FormMethod.Post in your Html form helper.

Comment: Nope, i'm using chrome, and i don't know how to see the data posted.

Comment: Just google how to launch "Developer Tools" (F12 I think) and check out the "Network" tab..

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is it won't post the entire model since only the checkbox is a form value. I think you need to add an additional hidden value in your form to track the item number and then handle the checkbox values specially in the controller. The item number is appended to "checkbox" in the posted values to keep them distinct.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nro_Item)
        @Html.Hidden("Nro_Item", item.Nro_Item)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sucursal.descripcion)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area.descripcion)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sector.Descripcion)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBox("checkbox" + item.Nro_Item, item.ID_Estado)
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the controller only bind to the number item so it can be used to process the checkboxes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CargarRecibidos(List<string> nro_item)
    {

         foreach (string item in nro_item)
         {
            var checkbox=Request.Form["checkbox" + item];
            if (checkbox != "false") // if not false then true,false is returned
            {
                // Do the action for true...
            }
            else 
            {
                // Do the action for false
            }
         }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working, though it would be nice send the entire list back to the controller into the database.

Comment: No problem.  From your original code it looked like the only change to be edited is in the checkbox. If you want to make all of it editable you will of course need to add the appropriate edit fields, or at least as hidden fields. There is a post by Phil Haack that addresses this which might be useful.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx